# Watch directory for file changes

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, fsevents, kqueue

I want to monitor a directory (of thousands of files, with about 5 levels of sub directories) for when files are changed. I know I can use the FSEvents API to monitor a directory for when files change inside that directory, but I can't seem to figure out how to determine which file(s) changed. [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH4-SW2) reference suggests I build a binary tree and traverse the tree each time an event is triggered, is that the **best** way to determine which files were changed? If not, what are some *better* alternatives?

Is it better to recursively scan the directory and attach kqueue to every file? I'm not sure how well that would work on thousands of files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used [UKKQueue](http://zathras.de/angelweb/sourcecode.htm) before with mixed results.

I've recently become aware of a better solution, but I haven't tried this. If you only need to target Lion, I think that the new best-practice way to do this is to use an [`NSFileCoordinator`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSFileCoordinator_class/Reference/Reference.html). You implement the methods of `NSFilePresenter` to indicate which directory you're interested in (the `presentedItemURL` property) and the system will notify you when a sub item moves/changes/is deleted (via methods like `presentedSubitemDidChangeAtURL:`)

I'd love to hear how that works out if you do go that route.

Comment: Jesse, have you tried using NSFileCoordinator/NSFilePresenter to implement monitoring of some folder so far? I wasn't able to make this solution work—it simply doesn't notify me about any events.

Comment: @DaveNewman NSFileCoordinator only works if the program that's making the changes is using it as well. (i.e. it's an opt-in API) Most Cocoa programs will do this; are the changes you're seeing being made by a lower-level API, perhaps?

Comment: I don't understand. For example, I've created a file presenter for my folder, say, '/Users/Dave/MyFolder'. Now when I drop files into this directory (drag&drop), only `presentedSubitemDidChangeAtURL:` method is being called by system, but not `presentedSubitemDidAppearAtURL:`. It also doesn't call `accommodatePresentedSubitemDeletionAtURL` when I delete some files in Finder. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @DaveNewman I'm not sure. At least you're getting callbacks, though. Perhaps you could start a new question about it with some more details about how you're setting up the monitoring to see if anyone knows what's going on.

Comment: @DaveNewman I am facing [exactly the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389726/nsfilepresenter-presentedsubitemdidappearaturl-method-never-gets-called)

Comment: As usual with Finder, "deleting" is actually "moving to trash" and "creating a file (atomically)" equals moving a buffered file to the destination. So you often only get a small subset of possible events and have to figure out what was going on in hindsight using context information.

Answer (score 6):

If you create your stream using **kFSEventStreamCreateFlagFileEvents** then you will get events for the changes to each file rather than just a notification of the change to the watched directory. Unfortunately this is only available in OSX 10.7 and later.