# NSFilePresenter -presentedSubitemDidAppearAtURL: method never gets called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfilecoordinator

I have an object which conforms to NSFilePresenter protocol that represents my document-based application document package. When a new file is created inside the package, either programmatically using NSFileManager with proper NSFileCoordination methods or via Finder i only got `-presentedSubitemDidChangeAtURL:` event, but not seeming so obvious in this case `-presentedSubitemDidAppearAtURL:`.

Is this an expected behavior or i am doing something wrong?

The comments on `-presentedSubitemDidAppearAtURL:` in NSFilePresenter state it clear:

> Be notified that a file or directory contained by the directory has been added. If this method is not implemented but `-presentedItemDidChange` is, and the directory is actually a file package, then the file coordination machinery will invoke `-presentedItemDidChange` instead.

Comment: I suppose you did not implement `-presentedItemDidChange`?

Comment: [Here](http://www.objc.io/issue-10/icloud-document-store.html)'s a nice posting related to this issue, and my conclusion is; Don't use `NSFilePresenter`.

Comment: GCD seems to be the way to go. [Handling Filesystem Events with GCD](http://www.davidhamrick.com/2011/10/10/handling-filesystem-events-with-gcd.html)

Comment: @Eonil like you have any options to choose from.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After struggling with this exact issue for quite a while, I opened a technical support issue with Apple. Their response was that this is a bug, and the only thing we can do right now is to do everything through `-presentedSubitemDidChangeAtURL:`.

I would encourage anyone encountering this issue to file a bug (https://bugreport.apple.com) to encourage Apple to get this problem fixed as soon as possible.

Comment: Did Apple's response to you indicate the extent of the "bug"? Is it simply that `-presentedSubitemDidAppearAtURL:`, `-accommodatePresentedSubitemDeletionAtURL:completionHandler:` et. al. are not yet handled by the NSFileCoordinator API, or are there cases where they would be called?

Comment: They didn't disclose any details to me, so I'm not sure, unfortunately.

Comment: Still same in 2014 Nov. I wasted about a day for this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Now at iOS 9.1 – still the same.

Comment: For god's sake, iOS 9.2 same bug.

Comment: 2016, iOS 10b7 and still going strong :)

Comment: It's 2021 now, and the bug is still not fixed in iOS 14.6

Comment: It's 2022 and this bug is still in macOS Monterey 12.0.1 -- which should be similar to iOS 15.x as they both rely on the Foundation frameworks NSFilePresenter and NSFileCoordinator. I considered that perhaps this had to do with the document based app having some automatic behavior in NSDocument -- or one of the hidden classes in the class-cluster. However adding another file presenter outside of the document subclass has the same behavior: only some of the delegate methods are called. and the most important method that provides a block **before** an item is deleted seems never to be called.

Answer (score -2):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSFilePresenter_protocol/

Your **presenter objects** are **not notified about changes made directly using low-level read and write calls** to the file. **Only** changes that go **through a file coordinator result in notifications**.

Comment: the original post mentions that he did use file coordinator. specifically, `with proper NSFileCoordination methods or via Finder`. And note that the Finder does use file coordination, so all the delegate calls should be made.